# Moving remove glyphicon inside input text box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, glyphicons

I want `glyphicon-remove` to be placed at the right end of input text box, here's my code-

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
  position: relative;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
  height: 100vh;
}
.content{
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
}
.fill_text{
  width: 20%;
  height: 42px;
  background-color: #DDD;
  border-radius: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 5px solid #E35F14;
  margin: 10px auto;
  outline: 0;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

  <div class="content">
  <input type="text" class="fill_text">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
  </input>
  </div>
```

I am setting the position of input text box as relative and I have tried by giving the position of the remove icon as absolute, but that's not working. Could you tell me why that's not working?

Comment: "Could you tell me why that's not working?" Yes, `<input>` elements are not allowed to have children. Inspect your HTML with Dev Tools and you'll see that the span is adjacent to the input, not inside it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> No elements are allowed inside `<input>` elements.

add this CSS

```
  .glyphicon-remove{
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      right: 30px;
      z-index:10;
    }
```

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
  position: relative;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
  height: 100vh;
}
.content{
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
}
.fill_text{
  width: 20%;
  height: 42px;
  background-color: #DDD;
  border-radius: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 5px solid #E35F14;
  margin: 10px auto;
  outline: 0;
  position: relative;

  
}
.glyphicon-remove{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 30px;
  z-index:10;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

  <div class="content">
  <input type="text" class="fill_text"/>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
  </div>
```

Comment: Why you are setting z-index as 10?

Comment: This will give priority to the glyphicon above input element . You can assign values to 1 too.

Comment: It can be ignored  But your glyphicon may be affected by another class